# Why is my sqlite query so slow in Qt5?

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt5, qtsql, qsqldatabase

In **Qt5.4** using **QSqlDatabase** with **sqlite3** on *Ubuntu14.04 64bit*:

First I open and call `transaction()` on the db.

Next I make 54 individual insert queries, each prepared, each deleted after execution.

Finally I call `commit()`.

All calls complete without error and still the execution time is horrible (around 500 ms total for 54 trivial inserts).

My computer is reasonably modern and has striped SSD disks for performance. When accessing the sqlite file using Sqliteman it is blazingly fast.

So *what is going on*?

Here is the insert:

```
void BottleRigStorage::upsertTag(Tag &tag){
    //ScopedTimer st("query time for tag");
    if(open()){

            QSqlQuery query(db);
            query.prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tags ("
                          "  id"
                          ", batchID"
                          ", retries"
                          ", good"
                          ", status"
                          ", color"
                          ", firstCheckTimestamp"
                          ", createdTimestamp"
                          ", modifiedTimestamp"
                          ", fulfilledTimestamp"
                          ") VALUES ("
                          "  :id"
                          ", :batchID"
                          ", :retries"
                          ", :good"
                          ", :status"
                          ", :color"
                          ", :firstCheckTimestamp"
                          ", :createdTimestamp"
                          ", :modifiedTimestamp"
                          ", :fulfilledTimestamp"
                          ");");
            query.bindValue(":id", tag.id);//8 chars
            query.bindValue(":batchID", tag.batchID);//8 chars
            query.bindValue(":retries", tag.retries);//int
            query.bindValue(":good",tag.good?1:0);//bool
            query.bindValue(":status", tag.status);//6 chars
            query.bindValue(":color", tag.color);//7 chars
            query.bindValue(":firstCheckTimestamp", tag.firstCheckTimestamp); //long
            query.bindValue(":createdTimestamp", tag.createdTimestamp);//long
            query.bindValue(":modifiedTimestamp", tag.modifiedTimestamp);//long
            query.bindValue(":fulfilledTimestamp", tag.fulfilledTimestamp);//long

            if (query.exec()) {
                //qDebug() << "Successfully updated tag database after "<<st.getIntervalCompleteString();
            }
            else {
                qWarning() << "ERROR: could not upsert tag with id " << tag.id<< ". Reason: "<< query.lastError();
            }
            query.finish();
        }

    else {
        qWarning() << "ERROR: DB not open for upsert tag sqlite3";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: And here is open() as requested:

```
bool BottleRigStorage::open(){
    if(!db.isOpen()){
        if(!db.open()){
            qWarning() << "ERROR: could not open database. Reason: "<<db.lastError();
        }
    }
    return db.isOpen();
}
```

Comment: What does your profiler say?

Comment: Is there a profiler for sqlite?

Comment: Probably, but it's unlikely to be SQLite, and more likely to be something about the way you're using it. Profiling your application should reveal where that slow down is (or at least give a good hint).

Comment: The commented out ScopedTimer st("query time for tag"); part in the code measured the time to be spent in this function but I guess with a profiler I can see sub-calls too.

Comment: Are there any parallel accesses to that sqlite db?

Comment: Was it faster with Qt 5.3 ? or with 4.8 ? If there is a bug in Qt 5.4 sqlite driver lot's of people would be happy to know

Comment: No I explicitly separated my db into two different files to disallow concurrent access to this data

Comment: I Will check versions:-) but I need some sleep first

Comment: What function `open` does? BTW, you don't need `query.finish();`

Comment: I added code of open() to listing

Comment: What is the slowest call? The `query.exec()`, or the transaction commit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use prepare only once.  Your code is preparing query each
   time after QSqlQuery creation. You need to create
   QSqlQuery with preparing outside of function, and just use value
   binding and sql query exec in function:

   ```
   void BottleRigStorage::upsertTag(Tag &tag){
   //ScopedTimer st("query time for tag");
   if(open()){
           query.bindValue(":id", tag.id);//8 chars
           query.bindValue(":batchID", tag.batchID);//8 chars
           query.bindValue(":retries", tag.retries);//int
           query.bindValue(":good",tag.good?1:0);//bool
           query.bindValue(":status", tag.status);//6 chars
           query.bindValue(":color", tag.color);//7 chars
           query.bindValue(":firstCheckTimestamp", tag.firstCheckTimestamp); //long
           query.bindValue(":createdTimestamp", tag.createdTimestamp);//long
           query.bindValue(":modifiedTimestamp", tag.modifiedTimestamp);//long
           query.bindValue(":fulfilledTimestamp", tag.fulfilledTimestamp);//long

           if (query.exec()) {
               //qDebug() << "Successfully updated tag database after "<<st.getIntervalCompleteString();
           }
           else {
               qWarning() << "ERROR: could not upsert tag with id " << tag.id<< ". Reason: "<< query.lastError();
           }
           query.finish();
       }

   else {
       qWarning() << "ERROR: DB not open for upsert tag sqlite3";
   }
   ```

   }

   Query object in this case can be a private member and create, for example, after database initialization.
2. You can tuning sqlite database via pragmas. For example, next code will increase executing of queries:

   m_pDatabase->exec("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF");
   m_pDatabase->exec("PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY");

   More information about this you can reade [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite)

Comment: IMPORTANT: I found this to be illuminating http://beets.io/blog/sqlite-nightmare.html. Basically there is a bug in sqlite that makes it sleep for seconds instead of milliseconds in some cases. Worth the read.

Answer (score 2):

I was Facing the same issue when I had like 99 Programs and each and everyone of that had 99 Steps and I was reading that data from Pendrive from CSV file and inserting them into DB. it was taking more than 5 min but after that, I have made few changes in

**main.cpp**

```
   db.open();
   db.exec("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF");
   db.exec("PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY");
```

and added db commit on the class for insert query

**model.cpp**

```
qDebug()<<"can start a transaction PrgQuery:"<<QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();
query.prepare("insert query");
query.exec();
qDebug()<<"end transaction Step Query:"<<QSqlDatabase::database().commit();
```

This solved my problem and minimize the time to like 10 sec. Pretty Fast like Unlimited Power